# Angular 4 Google Maps API formcontrol update issue

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular4-forms

I've been trying to create the simplest autocomplete input possible where user writes down address, clicks on particular value from Google Maps API dropdown and after filling other gaps he/she is able to save reactive form onClick.

However, I am not able to inject proper value into FormControl. When user writes down 'Washi' and clicks 'Washington D.C.' value displayed in input is correct, but when I save my Form I get 'Washi' in Firebase database instead of 'Washington D.C.'. Here is my code:

```
<input id="address" type="text" class="form-control"  formControlName="address" />
```

And in xxxxx.component.ts :

```
ngAfterViewInit(){

  let input = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("address");

  this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(
    () => {
      let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {types: ['address']});

      autocomplete.addListener( 'place_changed', () => {

        const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        this.ngZone.run(() => {

          this.cd.detectChanges();
          this.myGroup.value.address = place.formatted_address;
          console.log(this.myGroup.value.address);
        });
      });
    }
  );}
```

Reactive Form is loaded OnInit and everything seems to be working fine. Console.log displays proper value but not the one that gets transferred into Database. Here is the save function:

```
save(myGroup: NgForm){

    this.user = this._firebaseAuth.authState;
    this.user.subscribe(
        (user) => {
            if (user) {
                this.userDetails = user;

                this.first.subscribe(snapshot => {

                        if (snapshot.exists() === false) {

                            firebase.database().ref('path').set({
                                record: this.myGroup.value
                            });

                        } else {
                            this.userDetails = null;
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    );

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody is interested in knowing the solution, all I had to do was to add helping variable that holds the value of google autocomplete. Then (onClick) I declare that the value of FormControl is the same as the value of helping var.